# Existence of entire function having a desired property

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a non constant entire function such that :

(a) $f^{(n)}(0)=3^n $ for $n$ even and $f^{(n)}(0)=(n-1)!$ for $n$ odd

(b) $f$ is analytic in $|z|<1$ $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ $= 2 ,3 ,4 ...$

Regarding (b), I think that there is no analytic function since $f(z)=\sqrt z$ is not analytic in $|z|<1$.

I don't know the answer to (a).

Comment: Hint for (a): $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n z^{2n}}{2n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n!)z^{2n+1}}{2n+1!}$.

Comment: If $g(z)$ is analytic and $g(\frac1n) = \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ then $g(0) = 0$. What is the order of this zero  ?

Comment: b) is correct. (It's just using the identity theorem)

Comment: @Cloudscape Why b) is correct f? $\sqrt{z}$ is not analytic at $0$ Using identity theorem $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ is the only function that satisfy the property and not analytic at $0$

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean by the order of 0 ? and How can I use the order of 0 to answer the question ?

Comment: $\sin(z)$ has a zero of order $1$ at $z=0$. Analytic functions have zeros of integer order, so that as $z \to 0$ : $f(z) \sim c \, z^k$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Here $k = 1/2$ and so $f(z)$ can't be analytic.

Comment: @MahmoudHassan As you doubtlessly guessed, this is PRECISELY what I meant: I wanted to indicate that I agree with your solution.